# Sqlite3 database file doesn't work in android device[Corona SDK]

Tags: android, sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I tried to copy database file to systems.documentsDirectory in order to be able to write to database file in device as referred here: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/pathForFile.html

However, it seems not working in the device. Could you please analyze the code and tell me where I am doing wrong?

--IN DAO MODULE

```
local sqlite3 = require "sqlite3"

Dao={}

path = system.pathForFile( "barfi" , system.DocumentsDirectory )

db = sqlite3.open(path)
```

--IN PROJECT FOLDER (saved as)

barfi.txt

--IN MAIN

```
local function copyFile( srcName, srcPath, dstName, dstPath, overwrite )
    local results = true                -- assume no errors

    -- Copy the source file to the destination file
    --
    local rfilePath = system.pathForFile( srcName, srcPath )
    local wfilePath = system.pathForFile( dstName, dstPath )

    local rfh = io.open( rfilePath, "rb" )              
    local wfh = io.open( wfilePath, "wb" )

    if  not wfh then
        print( "writeFileName open error!" )
        results = false                 -- error
    else
        -- Read the file from the Resource directory and write it to the destination directory
        local data = rfh:read( "*a" )

        if not data then
            print( "read error!" )
            results = false     -- error
        else
            if not wfh:write( data ) then
                print( "write error!" ) 
                results = false -- error
            end
        end
    end

        -- Clean up our file handles
        rfh:close()
        wfh:close()

        return results  
end

copyFile( "Barfi.txt", nil, "Barfi", system.DocumentsDirectory, true )
```

Comment: Sorry, I think the database is working correctly in the device. It must be smt else that corrupts the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working nice. The database is working in the device. It must be smt else.